# Flow to Send An Email for every unique person in a list?

Tags: email, sharepoint

I have a system being developed that calculates training completed at work, and then calculates an expiry date, with a status based on how far it is. Currently it calculates if a course is at a Warning (within 6 months of expiring) and Expired. This is all done on powerapps and sharepoint.

I wanted to make a flow that takes from that SharePoint list and splits the table into just a table of all the training in Warning, and all the data that is Expired. I've done this, and then sent off an email to the team leaders.

The issue is, I want to use this same table to send an email to the people within the list, to remind them that their training is expiring.
Here's a loose example:

| User | Training Status |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | Warning |
| Person A | Expired |
| Person A | Warning |
| Person B | Expired |
| Person C | Warning |
| Person C | Expired |

I want the flow to send an email to person A, including all 3 courses that are noted, then another email to B, and a third one to C. Doing this by a "For each item" would end up sending 3 emails to person A, when I only want one email. How would this be done?

[Heres an example of the flow as it is currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ5En.png). The "Status" field is automatically calculated on SharePoint and as a result does not work properly with flows, so I needed a workaround to get it functioning. This then gets converted to HTML for the email and is sent out to the admins.

If there is anything else I can supply to help please let me know.

Many Thanks.